# Phpmyadmin error in dockerfile how to solve this?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Right now i am creating an image to run a cms in docker. the docker file code is written down:

```
From ubuntu:latest


RUN  apt-get update
ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get install -y  apache2
Run apt-get install -y php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN service mysql start
RUN apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y nano
RUN wget https://www.exploit-db.com/apps/312e42aeda0b0b163066b4ff401cae6d-bloofoxCMS_0.3.5.zip
RUN unzip 312e42aeda0b0b163066b4ff401cae6d-bloofoxCMS_0.3.5.zip
RUN mv bloofoxCMS_0.3.5 /var/www/html/
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/bloofoxCMS_0.3.5/media/files
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/bloofoxCMS_0.3.5/media/images
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/bloofoxCMS_0.3.5/media/txt
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/bloofoxCMS_0.3.5/system


 

CMD [ "echo' , "Image crated]
```

But when the bulid starts and phpmyadmin starts downloading it gets stuck. It asks connect to db common yes or no when i type yes it stucks. Help me how to solve this.

Comment: You probably need to run both MySQL and phpMyAdmin in separate containers; a container runs only one process and `RUN service ... start` in the Dockerfile doesn't actually do anything.